# How to deactivate a plugin when another plugin is activated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, magnific-popup, smooth-scrolling

I'm using Magnific-Popup.js and EaseScroll.js -- they don't work well together. Here's an example: http://codepen.io/natasha_r21/pen/QGrovp

As you can see, when I open an image with the lightbox, the smooth scroll continues to work in the background and then when I close the lightbox, regular scroll comes back. I want to keep the smooth scroll on the page and deactivate it when the lightbox is opened and reactivate it when the lightbox closes.

I've tried a few things, and have had no luck. I've tried disabling the background while lightbox is opened, and the page just stops scrolling in general once the lightbox closes.

This is where I am now:

```
var myFunc = function(easeScroll){
   $('#portfolio').removeeaseScroll()
}
```

Am I completely off?

Comment: What browser/OS are you seeing this in? I tried your example code and it's working perfectly on Chrome, FF and Edge on Win10.

Comment: Windows or MacOS?

Comment: I'm currently using Windows

Comment: Is it possible you have a browser plugin that's causing a conflict? When I run the example code you posted above, I get the easing on scrolling. Then I click an image, then close the resulting lightbox and try scrolling again and it seems to still be scrolling with easing.

Comment: that's strange, I don't have any plugins installed on my chrome?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130158/discussion-between-rubyred2-and-george-kendros).